# Difference in Unicode behaviour between `\w` vs `[[:alpha:]]` in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

(For this question, ignore the number and underscore matching of `\w`, which is irrelevant to the discussion here.)
According to the [Oniguruma docs](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE), both the shorthand character classes like `\w` and POSIX classes like `[:alpha:]` have similar behaviour with regard to Unicode: they have simple ascii behaviour for "Not Unicode Case" (I assume that means the string's `encoding` is not a Unicode one), and a different behaviour that uses Unicode properties for "Unicode Case".

From that documentation, it sounds as in a case where one of those uses Unicode properties, the other will also use them. However, in practice they seem to differ: the POSIX classes use Unicode properties automatically, whereas the `\w` type classes have to be explicitly marked with `?u` to use Unicode property based matching:

```
$ ruby -e 'print("~café.".encoding)'
UTF-8
$ ruby -e 'print(/[[:alpha:]]+/.match("~café."))'
café
$ ruby -e 'print(/\w+/.match("~café."))'
caf
$ ruby -e 'print(/(?u)\w+/.match("~café."))'
café
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.6p384
```

Is this a bug, or is my interpretation of the docs wrong? (And what exactly does `?u` do, could someone link to where it is documented?)

Comment: Ruby's [`RegExp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.6/Regexp.html) isn't necessarily identical to Oniguruma. The Ruby docs do say that `\w` is ASCII whereas `[[:alpha]]` is Unicode-aware. Neither one seems to say anything about `(?u)` though. I tend to use `\w`, `\s`, ... if I specifically want ASCII-ish behavior and `\p{...}` otherwise.

Comment: `u` is actually described [in the Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Encoding).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The trailing `u` is not the same as `(?u)`: `/\w+/u.match("~café.") # => #<MatchData "caf">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 2.0, Ruby uses [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo), an Oniguruma fork that supports more features implemented in Perl 5.10.

If you compare the doc you linked (Oniguruma) with [Onigmo's doc](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE) you can see a difference between the `\w` descriptions:

- Oniguruma:

> \w       word character
>
> ```
>        Not Unicode:
>          alphanumeric, "_" and multibyte char.
>
>        Unicode: General_Category -- (Letter|Mark|Number|Connector_Punctuation)
> ```

- Onigmo:

> \w       word character
>
> ```
>        Not Unicode:
>          alphanumeric and "_".
>
>        Unicode: General_Category -- (Letter|Mark|Number|Connector_Punctuation)
>
>        It depends on ONIG_OPTION_ASCII_RANGE option that non-ASCII char includes or not.
> ```

As you can see, there's no more this **"and multibyte char."** that doesn't make sense (at least for me) and that is probably a typo. Whatever, it's very unclear.

The `u` modifier switches the shorthand character classes from "Not Unicode" (default) to "Unicode".
That's why you obtain only `caf` without it and `café` with it when you try to match it using the character class `\w`.

On the other side the character class `[[:alpha:]]` seems to be already extended by default to unicode characters since it matches "café" without the u modifier. A start of explanation can be found in the doc:

> It depends on ONIG_OPTION_ASCII_RANGE option and
>       ONIG_OPTION_POSIX_BRACKET_ALL_RANGE option that POSIX brackets
>   match non-ASCII char or not.

But you can force it to ascii using the `(?a)` modifier.

Comment: Thank you! This combined with the Extended groups options described at https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE#L239 seem to explain what's happening correctly.